# IllegalArgumentException when writing bytes to file

Tags: java, clojure, io, byte

```
(ns huffman.core
  (:use [clojure.java.io :only [output-stream]]))

(defn use-output-stream-1 []
  (with-open [o (output-stream path)]
    (.write o (unchecked-byte 255))
    (.write o (unchecked-byte (Integer/parseInt "01010101" 2)))
    ))

(defn rb [b]
  (unchecked-byte (Integer/parseInt b 2)))

(defn use-output-stream-2 []
  (with-open [o (output-stream path)]
    (.write o (unchecked-byte 255))
    (.write o (rb "01010101"))
    ))
```

`use-output-stream-1` works as expected and the written file has been verified. I do not understand by `use-output-stream-2` throws an error.

```
huffman.core> (use-output-stream-1)
nil
huffman.core> (rb "01010101")
85
huffman.core> (use-output-stream-2)
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: write for class java.io.BufferedOutputStream  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)
huffman.core>
```

**EDIT**. I assumed that this is something to do with evaluation order so I wrote a macro.

```
(defmacro rb-macro [b]
  `(unchecked-byte (Integer/parseInt ~b 2)))

(defn use-output-stream-3 []
  (with-open [o (output-stream path)]
    (.write o (unchecked-byte 255))
    (.write o (rb-macro "01010101"))
    ))
```

This seems to solve the problem, but I would like to understand what is going on. I don't see why `(rb "01010101")` is not first evaluated and then the result passed to `.write`

Comment: `BufferedOutputStream.write` expects an int (even though it only writes a single byte). Clojure's type coercion system coerces a unboxed byte (like the one that is returned by special functions like `unchecked-byte`) to an int (https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Reflector.java#L470), but doesn't coerce a boxed Byte (such as the one returned by a user-defined function). You can re-unbox the parameter before passing it to write: `(.write o (byte (rb "01010101")))` should work.

Comment: Using a type hint will similarly help: `(.write o ^byte (rb "01010101"))`, or `(.write o ^int (rb "01010101"))` will produce the identical result.

Comment: @AlephAleph, could you just copy paste into an answer (if you want some internet points) if not, then I'll just delete the post. Just to check: user defined functions *always* return boxed types?

Comment: My understanding is yes; the only exception is that you can give a `^long` or `^double` type hint for a function in order to avoid boxing a numeric return value and have faster arithmetic. Would be good if someone more experienced could comment in case if I missed some edge cases.